# Diophantine equation over Z[i]

Tags: diophantine-equations

I'm trying to generate the set of solutions of a specific diophantine equation over Z[i].
The equation is the following:

$$ z_1^2 + z_2^2 + z_1*z_2 + 39 = 0$$

with $ z_1$ (resp $z_2$) such that $\exists a,b \in \mathbb{Z} , z_1$ (resp $z_2$) $= a + ib $

Is there a specific tehnique to deal with Gaussian Integers in Diophantine equations ?

Regards

Comment: The equation asks in effect to write $-39$ as a norm $N_{K/{\bf Q}(i)}(z)$,
where $K = Q(i,\sqrt{-3})$ is the 12th cyclotomic field
and $z = z_1 - e^{2\pi i /3} z_2$.  The relative unit group
has rank $1$, so this equation behaves like a Pell's equation,
with finitely many families of solutions each obtained from
a linear recurrence of degree 2 with constant coefficients.
Some small solutions are $(2i,5i)$, $(3+4i,-3+4i)$, $(6+5i,-6+5i)$.


Comment: Thanks for your comment !
I've been able to generate those small solutions.
But I'd like to generate all primitive solutions and to find this linear reccurence relation/

Comment: For starters, if $z_1,z_2 = a \pm b i$ then we get $3a^2 - b^2 = -39$,
which actually is a Pell equation (with non-unit discriminant).
The resulting recurrence must already give some positive fraction
of the solutions, and then a few linear transformations (probably
coming from roots of unity, like $(z_1,z_2) \mapsto (z_1,-z_1-z_2)$)
should provide the rest.  What do you need this for?


Comment: Thanks.
Just to clarify:
Is the equation $3*b^2 - a^2 = 39$ ?
With this Pell equation, I only generate conjugate solutions, and I'm not sure to understand what you mean with "a few linear transform". How can I be sure to have all the families ?

Comment: Sorry: $3a^2-b^2 = -39$ is right, but that equation has no solution,
so we must multiply $z_1,z_2$ by $i$ to get $ia \pm b$, and then it's $3a^2-b^2=39$ which is the equation you gave.  At the point
the linear transformation $(z_1,z_2) \mapsto (z_1,-z_1-z_2)$ and its iterate converts conjugate solutions to two other families, which together with $ia \pm b$ seems to give half the solutions; probably another linear transformation gives the others.

Again I ask: what's the source of this problem?



Comment: This is related to a Number Theory/Cryptography course (The point is to study solutions of those kind of equations). That's why, I would have liked a generic method or some papers about this topic (did not find anything relevant on Google).
How do you know the total set of solutions ?

Comment: No more idea about describing the other families of solution ?
I've been able to find a few solutions like $(12,-4i),(-3+14i)$, but I can't find any recurence formala. Would you have any hint ?